# Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@b65df5f -- permission denied for window type 2010

Tags: android, android-permissions

Hi im getting this exception:

> Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@b65df5f -- permission
>   denied for window type 2010

I already added `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`

Here is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver
        android:name="com.lockscreen.wipe.MainActivity$DeviceAdminSampleReceiver"
        android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description"
        android:label="@string/sample_device_admin"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.lockscreen.wipe.LockscreenIntentReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

...

</manifest>
```

Java:

```
public class LockscreenUtils {

    // Member variables
    private OverlayDialog mOverlayDialog;
    private OnLockStatusChangedListener mLockStatusChangedListener;

    // Interface to communicate with owner activity
    public interface OnLockStatusChangedListener
    {
        public void onLockStatusChanged(boolean isLocked);
    }

    // Reset the variables
    public LockscreenUtils() {
        reset();
    }

    // Display overlay dialog with a view to prevent home button click
    public void lock(Activity activity) {
        if (mOverlayDialog == null) {
            mOverlayDialog = new OverlayDialog(activity);
            mOverlayDialog.show();
            mLockStatusChangedListener = (OnLockStatusChangedListener) activity;
        }
    }

    // Reset variables
    public void reset() {
        if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
            mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
            mOverlayDialog = null;
        }
    }

    // Unlock the home button and give callback to unlock the screen
    public void unlock() {
        if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
            mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
            mOverlayDialog = null;
            if(mLockStatusChangedListener!=null)
            {
                mLockStatusChangedListener.onLockStatusChanged(false);
            }
        }
    }

    // Create overlay dialog for lockedscreen to disable hardware buttons
    private static class OverlayDialog extends AlertDialog {

        public OverlayDialog(Activity activity) {
            super(activity, R.style.OverlayDialog);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
            params.dimAmount = 0.0F;
            params.width = 0;
            params.height = 0;
            params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    0xffffff);
            setOwnerActivity(activity);
            setCancelable(false);
        }
    // consume touch events
    public final boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionevent) {
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

LockscreenUtils.lock() throws the exception...

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.lockscreen.wipe, PID: 8803
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lockscreen.wipe/com.lockscreen.wipe.LockScreenActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ffd0980 -- permission denied for window type 2010
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                   Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ffd0980 -- permission denied for window type 2010
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:789)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
                      at com.lockscreen.wipe.LockscreenUtils.lock(LockscreenUtils.java:33)
                      at com.lockscreen.wipe.LockScreenActivity.lockHomeButton(LockScreenActivity.java:178)
                      at com.lockscreen.wipe.LockScreenActivity.onCreate(LockScreenActivity.java:75)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: `... permission denied ...` stinks of Marshmallow+

Comment: @KlingKlang ok so whats the solution? :SS

Comment: Requesting permissions at runtime, which is the new delight Google introduced with Marshmallow just to annoy us developers something more..